# What is the best way of organizing thread pools in netty

Tags: java, netty

I have an application that accept request, proxy it, make some response body serialization and send serialization result to some storage via http. Netty is needed as server and http client.

I use the same eventLoopGroup for Netty server(IO task) ,for Netty http client (IO bound task), and also for response serialization (CPU bound task).

Does it ok to have the same eventLoopGroup for this case or I need to use the different thread pools?

Comment: @Norman Maurers answer is correct. Keep in mind too that with a proxy you will want to keep context switching in mind [Netty Best Practices](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-facebook-eng-netty/slides.html#26.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how heavy the serialisation is, depending on this you may want to offload it to another thread. That said it is impossible to give a correct answer here as you can only find out by profiling.